# Programmatic layout constraints causes rotation not to resize base UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

So i'm creating a UIViewController subclass with two elements: A header UIView and a UITableView below it.

```
----------------
||------------||
||Header View ||
||------------||
||------------||
|| Table View ||
||            ||
||            ||
||            ||
||------------||
----------------
```

I am adding constraints to the Header view and Table View in the init code as follows:

```
- (void)setupHeaderView
{
    self.headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    self.headerViewTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.headerView
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                   toItem:self.view
                                                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               multiplier:1.0
                                                                 constant:0.0];
    self.headerViewLeadingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.headerView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:self.view
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:0.0];
    self.headerViewTrailingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.headerView
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                        toItem:self.view
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                                      constant:0.0];
    self.headerViewHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.headerView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:nil
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:HeaderViewHeight];
}

- (void)setupTableView
{
    self.tableViewTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                  toItem:self.headerView
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0.0];
    self.tableViewLeadingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:self.view
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:0.0];
    self.tableViewTrailingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:self.view
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:0.0];
    self.tableViewBottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:self.view
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                                   constant:0.0];
}
```

These two views are added to self.view and are preceeded by a call:

```
self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

But the main problem is that upon loading this view, and rotating the device/simulator, the view maintains its portrait frame and maintains its origin so that the device window is horizontal but the view frame is still its portrait frame, leading it to be offscreen and having a blank black space next to it:

Screenshot supplied:
[image: Simulator Screenshot]

How do i maintain orientation changes propagated to the superview and thereafter to its subviews?

Comment: ....I feel like a moron.... That worked. Thanks. If you make a comment i'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you should have set header and table view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`.

Main view's `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` value should always remain to be `YES`:

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```